# combine \usepackage{times} and \fontspec \setmainfont

Tags: fonts, fontspec, characters, small-caps, times

I'm having difficulty finding a Times-like font which has support for Americanist phonetic symbols, bold, italic, bold italic and small caps.

Currently, I've got a setup using `xelatex` which gets me all but the last item on the list:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
BoldFont={Aboriginal Serif Bold},
ItalicFont={Aboriginal Serif Italic},
BoldItalicFont={Aboriginal Serif Bold Italic},
Mapping=tex-text]{Doulos SIL}
```

On my system (texlive on debian GNU/Linux), simply including `\usepackage{times}` will get me a font which has small caps, bold, italic, bold italic, but it doesn't have all the glyphs I need.

If I can figure out how to use that `\usepackage{times}` font with `fontspec`, I think I could fill it in as:

```
SmallCapsFont={NAMEOFUSEPACKAGETIMESFONT}
```

in the options for `\setmainfont`.

Alternatively, if there's a Times-like font which is going to be freely available, I could use that.

So, my practical question is: what font can I use to get times small caps?  I've tried with Aboriginal Serif, Doulos SIL, Nimbus No9 Roman L, Times New Roman, none seem to have the small caps.

My principled question is: is there a way to use the metafont `\usepackage{times}` font as one of the font types in `\setmainfont`?

To make some minimal examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
LARGECAPS \textsc{smallcaps}
\end{document}`
```

and compile with xelatex, ^^^ that works.

If I add `\usepackage{times}` that also works.

But if I add `\setmainfont{X}` where X is any one of 
 * Doulos SIL
 * Aboriginal Serif
 * Times New Roman
 * TeX Gyre Termes
 * STIXGeneral

I just seem miniscules instead of small caps.

Comment: Have you tried the `XITS` and `STIX` font families?

Comment: @Mico Not yet, this is for a publication which requires a Times or a clone thereof.  Can you say a bit more about these families and how to install/invoke them.  Your comment is intriguing but terse.

Comment: `XITS` and `STIX` are both freely-distributed Times Roman clones available in OpenType format. If you have a fairly recent vintage of TeXLive, you may be able to just type `\setmainfont{XITS}` and take it from there. If not, check out the homepages of [XITS](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/xits/) and [stix](http://www.stixfonts.org/) for more information about these fonts and how you may download and install them.

Comment: @Mico I found the STIX fonts on my system and tried STIXGeneral, but to no avail.  I also constructed some minimal examples (added to question).

Comment: As far as I know, the only Times clone you mention that has small caps is TeX Gyre Termes. Is Aboriginal Serif available?

Comment: the times package doesn't use a metafont font it assumes the use of the original Adobe Times Postscript font in type1 format.

Comment: Is your question this: "Is there a Times font with small caps?"? It's a bit hard to tease out from your post what you're actually asking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only Times clone that has small caps is, as far as I know, TeX Gyre Termes. Thus this works, but of course you don't get fancy small caps glyphs (just the Latin letters). But, apparently, also Doulos SIL has them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Aboriginal Serif}

\begin{document}
LARGECAPS \textsc{smallcaps}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want Doulos SIL as main font, here's the complete setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  BoldFont={Aboriginal Serif Bold},
  ItalicFont={Aboriginal Serif Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={Aboriginal Serif Bold Italic},
  %SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},
  %SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]{Doulos SIL}

\begin{document}
LARGECAPS \textsc{smallcaps} \textbf{Bold} \textit{Italic}
\textbf{\textit{Bold Italic}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your setup using `SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes}` and `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}` with Aboriginal Serif as the main font works!  

Strangely, though, the Doulos SIL version does not.  Even when I set `SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes}` and `SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}` I don't get small caps when setting Doulos SIL as the main font.

There's obviously a lot of background here that I don't understand.  I'm happy that using Aboriginal Serif and TeX Gyre Termes solves my immediatel problem.

However, if you could point me to any "further reading", that'd be great!

Comment: @apexofservice What's your version of Doulos SIL? Mine is `Version 4.112`. You should be able to find it with your system font manager.

Answer (score 2):

try it this way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% Times and math
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
  BoldFont={Aboriginal Serif Bold},
  ItalicFont={Aboriginal Serif Italic},
  BoldItalicFont={Aboriginal Serif Bold Italic},
  Mapping=tex-text.
]{Doulos SIL}
...
```

Comment: FWIW, using this preamble generates a font warning: 

`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape EU1/DoulosSIL(0)/m/sc' undefined (Font) using \`EU1/DoulosSIL(0)/m/n' instead on input line 115.`

Comment: and which one??

Comment: Sorry, I take that back, I get the font warning either way.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the fonts that you say don't have small caps **do** have small caps. Could you provide a MWE that'll show us that you don't get small caps with these fonts?

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent = 0em
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Path = M:/MyStuff/Fonts/timesnewroman6.85/, UprightFont = *.ttf]{times}
\newfontfamily\Doulos[Path = M:/MyStuff/Fonts/DoulosSIL-4.110/, UprightFont = *-R.ttf]{DoulosSIL}
\newfontfamily\TeXGyre[Path = M:/MyStuff/Fonts/tg-2.005bas/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/, UprightFont = *termes-regular.otf]{texgyre}
\begin{document}
Times New Roman: LARGECAPS \textsc{smallcaps}\\
Doulos SIL: {\Doulos{LARGECAPS \textsc{smallcaps}}}\\
TeX Gyre: {\TeXGyre{LARGECAPS \textsc{smallcaps}}}\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your example doesn't work because paths aren't right.  I'm using GNU/Linux debian distro with texlive so tex stuff tends to be in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/  and fonts are probably somewhere under /usr/share.  I run fc-list to see installed system fonts but I don't know where ttfs are kept unless they're ones I've installed, in that case usually in ~/.fonts/  However, these are system fonts that I installed using apt-get so I'm not sure how to try your suggestion.  Nevertheless, you're probably right that these guys have the small caps and there's something funky about my invocation.

Comment: @apexofservice I would be astonished if `apt-get` was installing fonts into your home directory. It probably installs them under `/usr/share/fonts`. But wherever it installs them, XeTeX/LuaTeX will use them. That is, these engines are designed so that they can use your system fonts and are not limited to those installed specifically for TeX.

Comment: @apexofservice The paths in my MWE are not wrong, they're just pointing to the folder where I keep my fonts. You need to specify the path where you keep them on your computer. But, if you have installed these fonts as system fonts, there's no need to specify any path at all, you can just use ``\setmainfont{Times New Roman}``, ``\newfontfamily\Doulos{Doulos SIL Regular}`` and ``\newfontfamily\TeXGyre{TeX Gyre Termes}``.