# Unicode-math, Mathastext and Siunitx's \ohm

Tags: luatex, siunitx, unicode-math, mathastext

The ohm unit of Siunitx does not appear if I use `unicode-math` and compile with `LuaLatex`.

It works again if I comment out either the `\usepackage[]{mathastext}` or the `\usepackage{unicode-math}` (with the following `setmathfont`).

Do you know why?

Read & Edit Link: https://www.overleaf.com/8071802kdjtvztfybtv

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[greek,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\fontfamily{courier}
\usepackage[]{mathastext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=setB,StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \si{\ohm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does it work if you load siuinitx before unicode-math?

Comment: you are using luatex so you shouldn't be using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @Fox Well, it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, but commenting it out doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oh true (otherwise I'd have posted it as an answer) but it's actually not unrelated as characters go when encodings are not as expected and unicode-math loads fontspec and they both assume Unicode encoded fonts so specifying T1 encoding doesn't help actually it does no harm either as you load fontspec later (via unicode-math) which fixes it up, and the fix Fox suggested of moving unicode-math even later is consistent with that

Comment: What's the reason for loading `mathastext` along with `unicode-math`? And why `textgreek` with LuaLaTeX? Besides `fontenc` that shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Mico Nothing, I mixed it up with XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `XITS Math` as the math font, there's little point in also loading the `textgreek`, `courier`, and `eucal` packages. If you load the `mathastext` package, its `\Omega` symbol will be used by `\si{\ohm}`.

As others have already commented, one shouldn't load the `fontenc` package under LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[greek,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathastext} % for "\si{\ohm}"
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{XITS}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[version=setB,StylisticSet=1]{XITS Math}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\si{\ohm} vs.\ $\Omega$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Imho one shouldn't use mathastext together with unicode-math. The documentation actually says it too: " Particularly in the latter case (i.e. using unicode-math) you probably don’t need, don’t want, and should not use mathastext".

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - A useful quote! :-) I assume there was a reason why the OP was loading the `mathastext` package; maybe it was to access the specific shape of the uppercase-omega glyph for use in `\si{\ohm}`. Maybe the OP will weigh in with a comment?

Comment: I used `mathastext` and `eucal` in order to have non-italic variables distinct from script font variables. I used them before adding `XITS` package to my full-length document. I didn't know the exact scope of `XITS` and so I didn't know which package became superfluous after adding it.

Comment: By the way, I lost my small caps with `\textsc{...}` by correction the problem with the suggestions here.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro - Does your code contain the instruction `\setmainfont{XITS}`?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I just solved that problem with the options `[SmallCapsFont={TeX Gyre Termes},SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps}` in that command. Maybe Courier doesn't have small caps?!

Comment: I found that options here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181183/combine-usepackagetimes-and-fontspec-setmainfont

Comment: @LeonardoCastro - Your second-to-last comment is quite confusing: "Termes", like XITS, is a Times Roman clone (a serif font), whereas "Courier" is a monospaced font. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico Hmmm... Yes, you're right. I want to use Small Caps only in a few titles. I want to let the text in Courier and those titles in Small Caps of whatever font. Can I have a monospace small caps font? What are my options?

Comment: Or better I want to have the right to change my main font whenever I want but let the font used for texts in `\textsc{...}` unaffected.

Comment: @LeonardoCastro - I'm afraid your two most recent comments are even more confusing than the earlier ones. Really. :-( Please create a *new query* in which you lay out what exactly you're trying to achieve with titles, "small caps or whatever" (what is this supposed to mean?), serif versus monospaced fonts, etc. These subjects are simply not that closely related to the text of your current posting.

Comment: @Mico I said "small caps OF whatever font". I assume that each font has different letters used for `\textsc` and I believe the Courier font lacks small caps letters, so I have to change to another font where I use the option `\textsc`. Actually, I already have my document working as I wanted, so I don't need a new query. I just can't explain exactly how it worked... :-) Maybe, I should learn more about all the packages I use.